# Calculation using 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables Games & Transaction
I use this formula in Games table, sum(EntryFee * Rake/(100 + Rake)*TotalEntry) to get a value

I use this query in Transaction table count(distinct UserID) to get a value

Now i want to divide the value of [sum(EntryFee * Rake/(100 + Rake)*TotalEntry)] and value of  [count(distinct UserID)]

for eg sum(EntryFee * Rake/(100 + Rake)*TotalEntry) = 90 and count(distinct UserID) = 3
then 90/3 =30
How can i do this in MYSQL

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data and desired output.

Comment: TotalEntry=100, EntryFee=30,Rake=16%... [sum(EntryFee * Rake/(100 + Rake)*TotalEntry)] this formula should give a value for eg: 1000, after that i want that 1000 to be divided by [count(distinct UserID)] this value for eg: 500.... Therefore 1000/500

Comment: this i already got. To give you a working query the table structure should be known. Also, it is required to be known on which column(s) those 2 tables need to be joined.

Comment: Table (Game) contains the column  "Totalentry,Entryfee,Rake" AND Table(Transaction) contains the column "UserID"

Comment: Please don't provide additional information in comments, but edit your question. And please don't explain sample input or expected outcome only with words. Just add this as tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (
    SELECT sum(EntryFee * Rake/(100 + Rake)*TotalEntry) FROM Games
)/(
    SELECT count(distinct UserID) FROM Transaction
) MyResult
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Games (EntryFee INT, Rake INT, TotalEntry INT);
CREATE TABLE Transaction1 (UserID VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO Games VALUES 
    (30,16,150),(45,20,100),(15,5,50),(25,20,300),(10,8,270);

INSERT INTO Transaction1 VALUES ('Daniel'),('David'),('John'),('Martha');

SELECT Games.EntryFee, Games.Rake, Games.TotalEntry, COUNT(distinct Transaction1.UserID) AS CountUser,
(Games.EntryFee * Games.Rake / (100 + Games.Rake) * Games.TotalEntry / COUNT(distinct Transaction1.UserID))
AS Calculate
FROM Games JOIN Transaction1 GROUP BY Games.EntryFee, Games.Rake, Games.TotalEntry;
```

Result :

```
+==========+======+============+===========+==============+
| EntryFee | Rake | TotalEntry | CountUser | Calculate    |
+==========+======+============+===========+==============+
| 10       | 8    | 270        | 4         | 50.00000000  |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 15       | 5    | 50         | 4         | 8.92857500   |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 25       | 20   | 300        | 4         | 312.50000000 |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 30       | 16   | 150        | 4         | 155.17242500 |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 45       | 20   | 100        | 4         | 187.50000000 |
+----------+------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

[sample query](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/c2182b9ba04b4413e12a54b9d1943e9a/)

Comment: where i can add the date range for eg i want between '2022-06-06 00:00:01' and '2022-06-07 10:00:00'

Comment: @Yogesh but your tables don't contain Date column then how will one can use a column which doesn't exist?

Comment: @Yogesh you can add **Where** before group by.. For Example `SELECT data FROM games JOIN Transaction1 WHERE yourTableName.Date BETWEEN '2022-06-06' AND '2022-06-07' GROUP BY Games.EntryFee, Games.Rake, Games.TotalEntry; `

eg : [link](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/cbebfe7bf06e3aa1918532be348b8a46/)